# Counting rows with variables in where clause

Tags: php, sql

I'm having trouble using variables in my SQL WHERE clause. I'm getting this error:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL
>   result resource

The code is:

```
$sql3= mysql_query("SELECT COUNT($ww) FROM data WHERE $".$ww." =  ".$weeknumber." ");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why is there an extra dollar sign just after `WHERE`?

Comment: Do you know what the variables .$ww. and .$weeknumber are evaluating to at runtime?

Comment: this extra dollar is to make it as variable , koz $ww is echoing the rows title in table .

Comment: $weeknumber is number of weeks stored in the table rows .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you count the table column by putting the columns name in your COUNT(column_name)?

Like so:

```
$sql3= mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(week_num) as wknum FROM data WHERE '$ww' =  '$weeknumber'"); 
$counted_weeks["week_num"]

// $counted_weeks["week_num"] will output your sum
//week_num would be a column name from your "data" table
```

Comment: yes it outputs the sum of rows and yes i have counting the cloumns name but the problem is after WHERE.  i have result like that  week3 ---2 , and week3---- 2 , so i want to get only one week3

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing `$ww` is referring to a column name. `$weekNumber` is obviously the value. In that case, your SQL query should look like this:

```
$sql3= mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(".$ww.") FROM data WHERE ".$ww." = ".$weeknumber." ");
```

I'm not a PHP guy, but I'm assuming you have the correct PHP syntax.

Comment: yes its coloumnname but your code didnt work and didnt count now at all

Comment: can you assign the query to a string and tell me the output of it.. something like $sqlToRun="SELECT COUNT(".$ww.") FROM data WHERE ".$ww." =  ".$weeknumber." ";
tell me the value in $sqlToRun

Comment: and also make sure you have a table data with _data_ in it.. :/

Comment: yes there is data in it :) , but your counting didnt work , it output 0

Comment: you still did not tell the generated query as I asked

Comment: yes please.. does one have to talk with php jargons to get through.. :/

Comment: it doesnt echo any error but the count its not counting , all results are 0

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking at this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).  As @Crontab mentioned I am not sure why you have a dollar sign in front of your where clause.

A couple other things to point out:
As it says in the link, you will need to make sure the query text is properly escaped.  Also, If I'm not mistaken (not familiar with PHP) do you need to explicitly concatenate the text instead of just using quotes?  (i.e. instead of "SELECT ... " ... " do you need to do "SELECT ... " + " ... ")

Answer (score 0):

php string formatting is perfect here, take your messy confusing concat string and make it clean and readable!

```
$sql3= mysql_query(sprintf("SELECT COUNT(%s) FROM data WHERE %s=%d", $ww, $ww, $weeknumber));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `$ww` is a valid column name and `$weekNumber` is an integer, this should work:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM data WHERE $ww = '$weekNumber'";
$rs = mysql_query($query);
$r = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs);
echo "Count: {$r['cnt']}";
```

Comment: I think $ww is a variable whose value is a column name

Comment: error           mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource